# Multiple Azure Functions Deployment in Azure Portal through VSCODE

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-functions, vscode-extensions

I have built an python azure function from a workspace and deployed on the azure portal which worked perfectly without any issues. But When I tried to create an another function on the same workspace, Deployment is leading to notifications "The azure workspace deploy submenu was already previously registered"

Step 1: The folder structure in VSCODE (My two separate functions Func_HTTPtrigger_SAPlogs & Func_HTTP_trigger_SQL)

[image]

STEP 2: When I tried to deploy the two functions from my single workspace, Its taking ages & not deploying in azure portal

[image]

I did tried creating another workspace with new Azure function However after deployment, its overwriting the existing function which was deployed in azure function earlier without creating a new function.

Can someone please advice how can we deploy multiple functions through VSCODE? In my perspective may be something needs to be adjusted in .vscode but dont know what is the change needs to be adapt

- For the reference
  **Extension json file looks like below:**

```
{
      "recommendations": [
        "ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions",
        "ms-python.python"
      ]
    }
```

- For the reference
  **launch json file looks like below:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9091,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}
```

- For the reference
  **settings file looks like below:**

```
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

- For the reference
  **settings file looks like below:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
        },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to deploy the 2 Python Http Trigger Functions, VS Code Azure-Functions extension has no glitch, it is loading and working successfully.

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

> The extension Azure Functions took a very long time to complete its last operation and it has prevented other extensions from running.

There is no issue registered in the Azure Functions with the above error.

I believe, this might happen due to large code base that is preventing to load other extensions in VS Code.

Check the Startup Activation time of your [extensions](https://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2019/11/fix-vscode-extension-performance-issue/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Extension%20Host,%20open,search%20for%20Show%20Running%20Extensions.&text=The%20first%20thing%20you%20can,each%20extension%20took%20to%20activate.) in VS Code and try to optimize it.
Still if the issue persists, open the Issue in the Official forum of Azure-Functions VS Code Extension on this [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues).

Comment: Thanks Pravallika for the answer. However I solved it by simple solution. Actually it was an issue with my office domain network, I tried to deploy the same function app on the VM with other domains & it worked!!